# Stripping empty tags from Plone content with Diazo

Tags: tinymce, plone, strip, diazo

I have a Plone site, themed with plone.app.theming. The problem I have is that the design is quite strict and doesn't assume any empty `<p>` elements or any other nonsense TinyMCE outputs. Such elements break the intended design. So I want to strip the empty elements from the content. I have tried inline xslt (that, according to http://diazo.org/advanced.html#inline-xsl-directives should be supported) like:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]"/>
```

But it didn't do the trick. In fact it made something weird. The empty `p` tags that I wanted to get rid of stayed intact but some other elements like

```
<a href="mylink"> <img src="../++theme++jarn.com/whatever.png" /></a>
```

turned into

```
<a href="mylink"></a>
```

with the image being striped out. Replacing `match="*[…` in the second template to `match="p[…` didn't strip out the images, but those nasty `<p>` were still in the output.

Any hints on how to get rid of the empty elements using Diazo rules?

**UPDATE** January 31, 2012
Here is the content from which I need the empty `p` tags to be stripped off:

```
<div id="parent-fieldname-text">
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p><section id="what-we-do">
<p class="visualClear summary">Not empty Paragraph</p>
<ul class="thumbsList">
    <li><a href="mylink"> <img src="../++theme++jarn.com/whatever.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="mylink"> <img src="../++theme++jarn.com/whatever.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</section></p>
</div>
```

The Diazo transformation rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"/>

    <!-- The default theme, used for standard Plone web pages -->
    <theme href="index.html" css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" />

    <replace css:theme-children="div.contentWrapper" css:content-children="#content" />            
</rules>
```

The output I get after applying the transformations to the Plone site is absolutely identical to the input while I would expect to get those 3 empty `<p>` tags after opening `<div>` to go away.

If I change the second template to match all elements like `match="*…` then the images get stripped out, but the empty `<p>` tags are still there.

Comment: It's also possible to tune TinyMCE settings so that it does not allow empty HTML DOM elements.

Comment: Any hint on where should I look, Mikko? Don't see anything like that in the TinyMCE Settings configlet

Comment: I bumped into this yesterday as TinyMCE was stripping away my <p>s. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements and https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/commit/ade51dde1e6e72cedc1e9225755a732fd2435335 Not sure if this applies old TinyMCE version shipped with Plone 4.

Comment: May be stupid, but you can achieve this with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: @spliter: Please, edit your question and provide an example (short) XML document. Tell us exactly which elements in this document must be deleted. Show the complete wanted result. Define precisely what you understand by "empty element". If you need only "empty `p` elements" to be stripped -- then my answer provides the wanted solution.

Comment: @dimitre-novatchev added the detailed information.

Comment: @toutp jQuery is not an option :)

Comment: @mikko-ohtamaa, seems like it's not in TinyMCE shipping with Plone yet since there is neither setting nor automatic intelligence in the editor I have on the site :)

Comment: @spliter: The newly-provided information shows that Diazo doesn't simply apply an XSLT transformation -- it may have its own language that resembles XSLT but is otherwise different, or it may do its own post-processing of the transformation results and add new elements -- like empty `p`s. In either case this is not an XSLT quwstion, so you need to remove the xslt tag and consult the available Diazo materials.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @DimitreNovatchev. If you confirm that this is not native XSLT thing, then it is Diazo + Plone specific indeed. That is sad of course. Thanks a lot for the investigation and clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. I've added an example of using Dimitre's xpath in a drop content rule at https://github.com/plone/diazo/commit/94ddff7117d25d3a8a89457eeb272b5500ec21c5 but it also works as the equivalent xsl:template. The example is pared down to the basics but it works using the complete example content in the question too.

Comment: Laurence, thanks for that test. I am going to replicate it in plone.app.theming since this is what I'm using atm. Can it be that there is something different between rules application in core diazo and plone.app.theming?

Comment: If it works in one it should work in the other as it's the same engine. To verify that, take a copy of your (unthemed) site content html with curl or wget and then apply your theme with the command line diazorun tool (add diazo to the eggs list for zopepy in your buildout). But my best guess is that you have some other rule that interferes. Try removing everything else from your rules.xml, see if it works, then add stuff back chunk by chunk until you find out what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the diazorun, Laurence. I am still testing it, but I am able to reproduce the issue described above even with it. I have got the content with wget, used rules.xml as a copy from your test, adding the theme reference as '<theme href="index.html" />'. The output still contained my empty <p> tags unless I wrote them in a compact form like '<p></p>' and not '<p> </p>'. Tried with both variants — yours and Dimitre's one. Testing further.

Comment: ok, the problem is found. When TinyMCE puts empty paragraphs in the output, it puts them with the non-breaking space that is not stripped as a real white-space. And, as I understand, Diazo runs XSL1.0 that means one can not use replace() to replace non-breaking spaces with real spaces for them to be stripped. So, the solution would be to get tidy, set it up to work with HTML5 (in my case) and let it clean the output of TinyMCE.

Comment: You should be able to match that with something like `<drop content="p[not(*) and text()='&nbsp;']"/>`

Comment: Laurence, I have tried that immediately after previous attempts failed, of course :) First of all, `&nbsp;` raises the error `Entity 'nbsp' not defined`. Second, non-breaking spaces are not presented as &nbsp; in the content (in the source they look exactly as the white-space due to encoding I assume). I have updated your test with the output straight from TinyMCE — https://github.com/plone/diazo/commit/ca1b3ab1d5ff2c2fdc058a2a03ec7f75caf53f4a I didn't update the rules with `text()='&nbsp;'` to not throw an error, but you can try locally

Answer (score 3):

**Just have this**:

```
<xsl:template match="p[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

**A complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<div>
 <p/>
 <p>  </p>
 <p><img src="..."/></p>
 <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div>
   <p>
      <img src="..."/>
   </p>
   <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, but it doesn't solve the thing for me. It's not pure XSLT issue, I suppose — it is closely related to the way Diazo (or more specifically plone.app.theming) work in Plone and how that technology applies transformations. Your code gives me exactly the same result as the on in my questions (that is, actually, taken from your answer on another issue ;))

Comment: @spliter: Sorry, I am completely confused. Please, define your question better. The provided transformation, when applied (by Diazo or any other compliant XSLT processor) must produce the same result as in this answer. If you get a different result this most probably means that Diazo uses a buggy, incompliant XSLT processor.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @dimitre-novatchev. It could be related to the processor Diazo is using, but I am not sure. That's why I am asking here ;) Added the more detailed information to the question